# sympy polynomial roots expressions

Tags: sympy, solver, polynomials

The polynomial roots expressions in sympy do not seem to work for edge cases (when the coefficient for the higher degree is 0). Can anybody explain why? Can we use /rely on the expressions for the roots?

```
import sympy as sy

lam = sy.symbols("lambda")
a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3 = sy.symbols("a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3")
eq = sy.Eq(a_3 * (lam ** 3) + a_2 * (lam ** 2) + a_1 * (lam ** 1) + a_0, 0)
polynome_solutions = sy.solve(eq, lam)
print(polynome_solutions)
for solution in  polynome_solutions:
    print(solution.subs([(a_3, 0), (a_2, 1), (a_1, 0), (a_0, -1)]))

lam = sy.symbols("lambda")
a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 = sy.symbols("a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4")
eq = sy.Eq(a_4 * (lam ** 4) + a_3 * (lam ** 3) + a_2 * (lam ** 2) + a_1 * (lam ** 1) + a_0, 0)
polynome_solutions = sy.solve(eq, lam)
print(polynome_solutions)
for solution in  polynome_solutions:
    print(solution.subs([(a_4, 1), (a_3, 0), (a_2, 0), (a_1, 0), (a_0, -1)]))
```

The results:

```
[-a_2/(3*a_3) - (-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)/(3*(27*a_0/(2*a_3) - 9*a_1*a_2/(2*a_3**2) + a_2**3/a_3**3 + sqrt(-4*(-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)**3 + (27*a_0/a_3 - 9*a_1*a_2/a_3**2 + 2*a_2**3/a_3**3)**2)/2)**(1/3)) - (27*a_0/(2*a_3) - 9*a_1*a_2/(2*a_3**2) + a_2**3/a_3**3 + sqrt(-4*(-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)**3 + (27*a_0/a_3 - 9*a_1*a_2/a_3**2 + 2*a_2**3/a_3**3)**2)/2)**(1/3)/3, -a_2/(3*a_3) - (-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)/(3*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27*a_0/(2*a_3) - 9*a_1*a_2/(2*a_3**2) + a_2**3/a_3**3 + sqrt(-4*(-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)**3 + (27*a_0/a_3 - 9*a_1*a_2/a_3**2 + 2*a_2**3/a_3**3)**2)/2)**(1/3)) - (-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27*a_0/(2*a_3) - 9*a_1*a_2/(2*a_3**2) + a_2**3/a_3**3 + sqrt(-4*(-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)**3 + (27*a_0/a_3 - 9*a_1*a_2/a_3**2 + 2*a_2**3/a_3**3)**2)/2)**(1/3)/3, -a_2/(3*a_3) - (-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)/(3*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27*a_0/(2*a_3) - 9*a_1*a_2/(2*a_3**2) + a_2**3/a_3**3 + sqrt(-4*(-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)**3 + (27*a_0/a_3 - 9*a_1*a_2/a_3**2 + 2*a_2**3/a_3**3)**2)/2)**(1/3)) - (-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)*(27*a_0/(2*a_3) - 9*a_1*a_2/(2*a_3**2) + a_2**3/a_3**3 + sqrt(-4*(-3*a_1/a_3 + a_2**2/a_3**2)**3 + (27*a_0/a_3 - 9*a_1*a_2/a_3**2 + 2*a_2**3/a_3**3)**2)/2)**(1/3)/3]
nan
nan
nan
[Piecewise((-a_3/(4*a_4) - sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) + (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3)) + 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2, Eq(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12, 0)), (-a_3/(4*a_4) - sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) + (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) - 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2, True)), Piecewise((-a_3/(4*a_4) - sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2 + sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) + (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3)) + 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2, Eq(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12, 0)), (-a_3/(4*a_4) - sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2 + sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) + (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) - 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2, True)), Piecewise((-a_3/(4*a_4) + sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) - (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3)) + 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2, Eq(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12, 0)), (-a_3/(4*a_4) + sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2 - sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) - (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) - 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2, True)), Piecewise((-a_3/(4*a_4) + sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2 + sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) - (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3)) + 2*((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**(1/3))/2, Eq(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12, 0)), (-a_3/(4*a_4) + sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2 + sqrt(-4*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(2*a_4**2) - (2*a_1/a_4 + 2*a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)/sqrt(-2*a_2/(3*a_4) + a_3**2/(4*a_4**2) - 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) + 2*(-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)/(3*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3)) - 2*(-(a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/6 + (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/16 + (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/216 + sqrt((-a_0/a_4 + a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**2/12)**3/27 + ((a_0/a_4 - a_3*(a_1/(4*a_4) + a_3*(-a_2/(16*a_4) + 3*a_3**2/(256*a_4**2))/a_4)/a_4)*(a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/3 - (a_1/a_4 + a_3*(-a_2/(2*a_4) + a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))/a_4)**2/8 - (a_2/a_4 - 3*a_3**2/(8*a_4**2))**3/108)**2/4))**(1/3))/2, True))]
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be solving a general third degree polynomial. One step of the solution normalizes the polynomial to start with 1, so dividing by `a_3`. The later substitution of `a_3` by zero causes a divide by zero which is expressed as 'nan' ("not a number").

Answer to the edited question:

Well, there doesn't exist a general algebraic solution for the fourth degree polynomial. So, the best you can hope for, is to give sympy  a specific higher degree polynomial and hope that one has a solution. Sympy just tries to do its best, and for that it has to make some assumptions, but it isn't always correct. No computational algebra system is perfect, and sympy certainly isn't the most sophisticated one for all purposes, but it's free and most importantly, open source.

*Can we use /rely on the expressions for the roots?*

Writing the equation with six unknowns, sympy doesn't differentiate between which one would be called an unknown and which would be called a parameter. Some assumptions are made to be able to make progress.

So, can we rely 100% on sympy's results? No, certainly not. Solutions need to be checked, and evaluated for fitness for the specific application. We can be pretty sure it works well for univariate polynomial equations. For more complicated cases, one often tops with the limitations of a computational algebra.

Looking at what [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Be%3D0) does with this specific equation, although I didn't check it, seems more appropriate, though very involved, and quite difficult to use in further calculations. Wolfram Alpha does seem to differentiate between parameters and unknown unknowns, which sometimes obliges you to use specific names for the parameters/unknowns. See for example what it does with the [rewritten equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xa%5E4%2Bya%5E3%2Bza%5E2%2Bwa%2Bv%3D0). Especially [this rewrite](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xa%5E4%2Bya%5E3%2Bza%5E2%2Bwa%2Bv%3D0%20for%20a) doesn't return what you would hope for.

Your encouraged to test out your specific kind of equation in [alternative systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) and report cases in [sympy's github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) for interesting examples where sympy doesn't perform as well as it should.

Comment: It gave me an idea that sympy assumes that the highest-degree coefficient is non-zero.

Comment: a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 = sy.symbols("a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4")
 eq = sy.Eq(a_4 * (lam ** 4) + a_3 * (lam ** 3) + a_2 * (lam ** 2) + a_1 * (lam ** 1) + a_0, 0)
 polynome_solutions = sy.solve(eq, lam)
 print(polynome_solutions)
 for solution in  polynome_solutions:
     print(solution.subs([(a_4, 1), (a_3, 0), (a_2, 0), (a_1, 0), (a_0, -1)]))

Comment: Gives wrong results for x**4 - 1 = 0, although the main coefficient is not zero.

Comment: Totally. Good answer. One point I'd like to clarify: "doesn't exist a general algebraic solution". Do you mean without using "Piecewise"?  I would like to check the expressions for the 4-th degree polynomials though. It doesn't seem right intuitively. What's the value of these expressions if they don't give the right answer for the simplest case? Is there any case when they give the correct results at all?

Comment: Well, a general quartic equation isn't a "simple case", as the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution) points out. Especially not if you, like sympy, don't distinguish between parameters and unknown variable. You need lots of cases and intermediate variables. Sympy's doesn't come with guarantees, only a best-effort solution. You always need to verify whether it's sufficient for your specific use case.